# how to run specific file in NX cloud nestjs?

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, nrwl-nx

```
folder structure: 

SDK-NODE
 -> config
 -> libs
  -> sample-sdk
   -> project1
    -> src
     -> lib
      -> testcase.spec.ts
```

Solutions Tried:

nx run project1:test --testFile= testcase.spec.ts

ng test project1 --test-name-pattern=testcase.spec.ts

ERROR
NX   Cannot find project 'project1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your project name probably `sample-sdk`.
since usually nx directory are something like this:

```
...
apps/
-> web-app
-> backend-app
-> etc-app
libs/
-> lib1
-> lib2
package.json
...
```

try
`nx run sample-sdk:test --testFile=libs/sample-sdk/project1/src/lib/testcase.spec.ts`